# mapStateToProps not updating component

Tags: react-native, redux

I am an experienced React Native coder, and have struggled 4 hours with this, feeling like I am wasting my life.
the mapstatetoprops does not update the component.

the code:
in component:

```
class UnreadChat extends Component {
...
  render() {
    console.log('---reloaded', this.props.unreadChatIds);//here it does not get reloaded after mapStateToProps receives 
    this.newMapStateToProps();
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
        aa
      </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { unreadChatIds } = state.unreadchats;
  console.log('---unreadChatIds', unreadChatIds);
    return { unreadChatIds };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, null
)(UnreadChat);

i
```

n redux:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  unreadChatIds: []
};

export default (state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(INITIAL_STATE)), action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case CHAT_SET:
        let unreadChatIds = state.unreadChatIds;
        if (action.payload.value === true) {
          if (unreadChatIds.includes(action.payload.chatId) === false) {
            unreadChatIds.push(action.payload.chatId)
          }
        }

        return { ...state, unreadChatIds };
      default:
        return state;
    }
};



Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
  Node: 8.10.0
  Yarn: 1.5.1
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
  react-native: 0.54.4 => 0.54.4 
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
```

Can you help me with a solution?
Does mapstatetoprops not get used any more?
What is a way to update a component when the redux state changes?

Thank you

Comment: In your reducer you're mutating the state by doing .push(action.payload.chatId),
change the line let unreadChatIds = state.unreadChatIds to let unreadChatIds = [...state.unreadChatIds] so you don't mutate the state directly

Comment: @Milenko You sir, are a savior. it worked. thank you from the bottom of my heart.